# given value of matrix, getting it's coordinate

Tags: r

I have matrix, I want to write a function, get the element of matrix and  return me the coordinate of number inside of matrix. could somebody give an idea how to implement it ?

```
> A
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   20
[2,]   21   17
[3,]   13   25
[4,]   21   11
[5,]   31   24
```

for example

> myfunction(11)

```
> 11
> row 3, col 1
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`which()` takes an argument, `arr.ind=TRUE`, which will return the indices of all `TRUE` elements in a logical matrix to  which it is applied.

```
## An example matrix
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(sample(1:100, 10), ncol=2)
m
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   27   86
# [2,]   37   97
# [3,]   57   62
# [4,]   89   58
# [5,]   20    6

## An example application 
which(m==58, arr.ind=TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   4   2
```

Answer (score 1):

Hardly worth contributing an answer such as this in light of Josh's answer, but an example of using arithmetic in R would be a custom function of the form:

```
getIndices <- function(flatMatch, nrow) {
  rows <- flatMatch %% nrow
  cols <- flatMatch %/% nrow + 1
  cbind(rows, cols)
}
```

This of course could be extended to consider multidimensional arrays, their reshaped counterparts, or even arrays that haven't been formed yet. Custom codes could provide some mild advantages in those cases, but R is pretty efficient with storage and representation of arrays, so that's a contrived example at best.