# function for getting coordinate of matrix element

Tags: r

I have matrix A, I want to get it's element coordinate (row and col) given element of that matrix.

I used which(A== number), but it doesn't give me the row and col number of given element.
does anyboday have idea which function I should use ?

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    6   11   16
[2,]    2    7   12   17
[3,]    3    8   13   18
[4,]    4    9   14   19
[5,]    5   10   15   20
```

For example, for given `element = 18`, I want to get `coordinate` like : `3, 4`

Comment: I think you need to clarify which are the new aspects of the current question compared to [the question you asked two days ago, which has an accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061202/given-value-of-matrix-getting-its-coordinate).

Answer (score 5):

Use `arr.ind=TRUE` in `which`

```
> A <- matrix(1:20, ncol=4)
> which(A==18, arr.ind=TRUE)
     row col
[1,]   3   4
```