# find specific values in a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix in R which looks liek this. It is called mad

```
     C.1 C.2 C.3
row1   1   2   3
row2  4   12  13
row3  5    7  12
row4  2    3   4
```

I want to go from mad[2,1] which is 4 in this case to search through column 2 and 3 for the value 4 to come up. In the example R should return that 4 is in mad[4,3]. I am sure there is a way to do that with grep. However, I don't use fixed characters like 4 in my example so I thought grep is not usabel because if i do grep("g[[k]][1,2]" ...) or something like this it will search for the pattern of strings.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `which(mad==4, arr.ind=TRUE)`?

Comment: Duplicated? [given value of matrix, getting it's coordinate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20061202/1315767)

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
which(mad ==4, arr.ind = T)
```